# Will updated prop values in the `useSelector` callback be used when they change?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I'd like to use a prop value from my component to retrieve a value from redux.

Will changes to that prop value trigger effects and a re-render?

For example, in the code below, would a change to the `organizationId` prop from a calling component result in the console message being logged with the new name?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function MyComponent({ organizationId }) { 

  const organizationName = useSelector(state => 
    state.organizations[organizationId].name
  );
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`organizationName changed to ${organizationName}`);
  }, [organizationName]);

  return (
    <>{organizationName}</>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this on a sample project?

Comment: Yes, if a `useEffect` hook dependency updates, the hook's callback will be called.

Comment: The edit to the title changes the meaning of the question to something different. 

I'm aware the useEffect is executed when its dependencies change, but I'm specifically wondering whether the prop change will impact useSelector (because the prop is used in useSelector).

Comment: Actually, both titles are rather meaningless since neither the `useSelector` or `useEffect` hooks trigger a component rerender. I see now what you were really wanting to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will.
The effect will be called because the `organizationName` is listed as a dependency.